# Configuring renamed TFS 2015 Server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Our TFS 2015 server recently got renamed, and I need to get it back online with the new server name.

When I try to reconfigure the Application Tier using the TFS admin tool, I'm getting the following error message:

*TF400860: The current version of the following service is not supported: Registry, Version: 8, MinVersion8.*

The TFS server is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and uses SQL Server 2014 for its databases.

Any help in resolving this error, or pointers to good documentation about solving the renamed TFS 
server problem would be appreciated.

Comment: This could be due to you are using a different TFS server 2015 version to reconfigure app tier. Make sure you use the same TFS 2015 update version say 2015.2 was your source TFS, use same to configure new app tier. refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e176e6d1-5d9e-46cb-935b-c8dad79ebe97/tfs400860-the-current-version-of-the-following-service-is-not-supported-registry-version-4?forum=tfsintegration

Comment: How did you rename your server? Have you checked @ChamindaC's comment?